# how to get folders and documents of document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml-query

I have used below code to get files in SharePoint. But using that code I am getting only files not folders. What I need is whole folder and documents in root directory. Please help me.

```
context.Credentials = new SP.SharePointOnlineCredentials(loginInfo.UserName, loginInfo.Password);
SP.List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(loginInfo.DocumentLibraryName);
context.Load(docList);
SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
SP.ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(listItems);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get items in the root, you should not be using the `scope` attribute

listing documents, as well as folders, is something that the query should already be doing

so, according to your request, you can update as follows,

```
context.Credentials = new SP.SharePointOnlineCredentials(loginInfo.UserName, loginInfo.Password);
SP.List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(loginInfo.DocumentLibraryName);
context.Load(docList);
SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
SP.ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(listItems);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```